# ¿Porque no me funciona correctamente la función AES_DECRYPT en php?

Tags: php, mysql

He encriptado una entrada en mysql y ahora quiero desencriptarla. ¿Que tengo mal aquí?

La `key` la tengo definida en una variable.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT AES_DECRYPT(nombre,'$key') FROM main WHERE nombre='$nombre'");
```

Estoy encriptando los datos usando:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO main (nombre, secondName) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$nombre','$key'), AES_ENCRYPT('$secondName','$key'))";
```

Comment: Hola marc, puedes mencionar cual es el error que te aparece y cual fue el código con el lo que encriptaste originalmente ?

Comment: No me aparece ningun error, encripta correctamente pero a la hora de desencriptar no me hace nada. Anteriormente me devolvia el valor guardado en la base de datos pero estaba desencriptado, ahora he querido encriptarlo pero a la hora de dar el valor desencriptado no me devuelve nada.

Answer (score 1):

El query no te devuelve nada porque estás buscando que nombre sea igual a `$nombre` y como el nombre lo guardaste cifrado, pues no va a coincidir. Debes cifrar el valor a comparar en el `WHERE`:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(nombre,'$key') FROM main WHERE nombre=AES_ENCRYPT($nombre,'$key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que **$nombre es el valor encriptado**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT AES_DECRYPT(nombre,'$key') FROM main WHERE nombre='$nombre'");
```

Puede ser que tengas que utilizar la funcion *CAST*, tu cliente de SQL puede ser que tenga problemas si no lo utilizas

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(nombre,'$key')) AS CHAR(50) FROM main WHERE nombre='$nombre'");
```

Siendo el insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO main (nombre, secondName) VALUES (CAST(AES_ENCRYPT('$nombre','$key')) AS CHAR(20), CAST(AES_ENCRYPT('$secondName','$key')) AS CHAR(40))";
```

Usa *CAST* en función del tipo de columna o variable que tengas declarado.